# Group by with results

Tags: sql

If I have this table:

```
UserID | Score1 | Score2
1      | 10     | 5
2      | 50     | 15
3      | 30     | 25
1      | 50     | 10
2      | 0      | 100
3      | 1      | 5
```

I want to sort this table to score1+score2, but I also want to get the seperate scores back.

But it has to be grouped by userId, and only returning the highest score of the user (so MAX score1+score2).

But I cannot do a group by because then I will rule out users with same scores. This is a headbreaker for me...

From above table the result should be:

```
UserID | Score1 | Score2 | TotalScore
2      | 0      | 100    | 100
1      | 50     | 10     | 60
3      | 30     | 25     | 55
```

Comment: What do you want to happen for UserID 1's scores for Score1, 50 & 40?  Do you want them added together, for 90?  Or do you want them Averaged?  Max score?  something else?

Comment: They have to be totaled, so order score1+score2 grouped by userid, but also it has to return the separate scores.

Comment: I understand you want to add score1 & score2.  I'm asking about the multiple entries of score1.  in your example data, that's 50 & 40.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread. No the query has to return only the highest score! I did not make that clear in my question.

Comment: With score I mean highest TOTALscore...

Comment: what database & version do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, Score1, Score2, Score1 + Score2 AS "Total"
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Score1 + Score2 DESC
```

you don't need a `GROUP BY` because it's not an aggregate function, it's just a calculated column.

### Edit

You need to do a join on your max total score and your user id after you've grouped.  Here's an example with a common table expression:

```
WITH maxScores AS (
    SELECT UserID AS "id", MAX(Score1 + Score2) AS "total"
    FROM scores 
    GROUP BY UserID
)
SELECT s.UserID, s.Score1, s.Score2, s.Score1 + s.Score2 AS "Total"
FROM scores s
JOIN maxScores m ON s.UserID = m.id
    AND s.Score1 + s.Score2 = m.Total
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work. It will take the MAX of each score, but it should be the MAX of each row and not from various rows... Difficult to explain.

Comment: edit your question to show your desired output along with your input.  then i might be able to help more.

Comment: I changed it now, is it more clear? It is hard to explain just with text :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select UserID, Score1, Score2
    from YourTable
    order by Score1 + Score2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```
declare @t table( id int, s1 int, s2 int)

insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (0, 10, 5)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (1, 50, 15)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (2, 20, 25)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (1, 30, 0)

select id, s1, s2, (s1+s2) as 'total' from @t order by (s1+s2) desc, id asc
```

```
1   50  15  65
2   20  25  45
1   30  0   30
0   10  5   15
```

Comment: Yes, but it has to be grouped by the UserId so that it only shows single rows.

Answer (score 1):

So then, is this what you want?

```
declare @t table( id int, s1 int, s2 int)

insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (0, 10, 5)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (1, 50, 15)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (2, 30, 25)
insert into @t (id, s1, s2) values (1, 40, 0)

select id, MAX(s1) max_s1, MAX(s2) max_s2, SUM(total) total from
(select id, s1, s2, (s1+s2) as 'total' from @t) a
group by id
order by total
```

I'm afraid you really did not specify what you want to do with `s1` and `s2` after grouping the rows with same `id` ...

Comment: This should return the highest `s1`, the highest `s2` and the sum of all scores for each user id.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT Q1.UserID, Q1.Score1, Q1.Score2, Q1.Total
FROM (SELECT UserID, Score1, Score2, (Score1+Score2) AS Total
    FROM myTable) AS Q1,
(SELECT UserId, Max(Score1 + Score2) As Total FROM myTable GROUP BY UserId) As Q2
WHERE Q1.UserId=Q2.UserId AND Q1.Total=Q2.Total
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer it? Presuming that you would want to include duplicates of the same score1 + score2 for the same id (if not change the DENSE_RANK to ROW_NUMBER)

```
create table #data (id int,score1 int, score2 int)
insert into #data Values (0,10,5)
insert into #data Values (1,50,15)
insert into #data Values (2,30,25)
insert into #data Values (1,40,0)

** edit for sorting as per question revision**
;with scores AS
(
SELECT
id
,score1
,score2
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score1 + score2 DESC) AS score_rank
FROM #data
)
SELECT 
id
,score1
,score2
,score1 + score2 AS sum_
FROM scores where score_rank = 1
ORDER BY score1 + score2 DESC
```