# SQl - select columns and group them

Tags: sql

I have a table like this below and i need the result to be like this when i run the query

**Results**

```
title | count
----------------
foo   | 3 
bar   | 2
```

**Table**

```
customer_id | title
-------------------
55          | foo
22          | foo
55          | bar <-- duplicate
23          | bar
55          | bar <-- duplicate
23          | foo
```

**UPDATE** Thank you all for the quick response!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by with results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156349/group-by-with-results)

Comment: A lot of people overlooked that `duplicate` annotation. Next time be a little more explicit when describing your problem.

Comment: i will, it's hard when you dont know what your are looking for!

Comment: @SinisterGlitch, accept answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to count the `distinct` customer ids, so you won't count the double Foo for customer 55.

If you need to, you can order the results by that count too, or you can just leave out the `order by` clause.

```
select 
  title, 
  count(DISTINCT customerid) as `count`
from 
  yourTable
group by 
  title
order by 
  `count` desc
```

Comment: Thank you my whole logic was way off while making those queries. now i know what to do in the future!

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as this:

```
select A.title, count(*) as count -- an usual count(*)
from
(select distinct customer_id, title -- this query removes the duplicates
from table) A
group by A.title  -- an usual group by
```

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server you can do it like this.

```
select 
    t.title     ,
    count(*)
from your_table as t
group by
    t.title
order by count(*) DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't give the requested result for the given example data.